# How to link .h and .m files to a new ViewController in Xcode 4.5?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

Ok so I've been reading tutorials and surfing through StackOverflow and I haven't been able to get an answer to this question.

I recently started developing iOS apps (this is my first one). I have a Tab Bar Controller and from there 5 different ViewControllers. As a default, it comes with FirstViewController and SecondViewController that I am able to modify their views in the StoryBoard and that I have them working "fine" for now. Now my question is how do I connect the other 3 missing ViewControllers to their respective .h and .m files? I tried creating a new Objective-C class with XIB user interface but I was not able to connect that XIB file to the main Tab Bar controller in the MainStoryboard.storyboard so I think I am missing something.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

Don't mix XIBs and storyboards. All you have to do is to create classes (declared in h and m files) that inherit from UIViewController without XIB files and specify the class name in the storyboard's object inspector. The "link" to the files is by referencing the class name in the inspector.

[image]

Comment: This is what I did, but I am modifying the background in the code, and when I run the simulator, it only shows me what I have in the story mode

Comment: Try adding some NSLogs to your code, see if it runs "viewDidLoad" for instance. If you're doing things in code that aren't reflected in your view then you're probably doing something wrong (bad IBOutlet hookups for example). What's your code for modifying the background?

Comment: Ok so I'm definitely doing something wrong but I don't know what it is. I have a Label in each ViewController saying 3rd, 4th, 5th respectively and before it used to say Third View, Fourth View, Fifth View. Whenever I run the Simulator, it keeps saying Third View, etc... Any idea of what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: UILabel? Are they attached to their respective IBOutlets?

Comment: I don't think so, how do I do that? Sorry I'm new to this

Comment: Sorry, mate. We could go on and on but this is totally unrelated to your question. There are literally hundreds of basic tutorials out there to get you started. Good luck

Comment: Any tutorial you recommend?

Comment: Anything by Ray Wenderlich or Apple's own tutorials. For basics I don't have a good recommendation, try Googling

Answer (score 2):

Answer by Stavash is actually correct but u need to do something more.

You have to link the view property to the referencing outlet of the corresponding file.

After linking the class name to the xib do the following.

In xib file select the view controller -> in connections inspector -> drag and connect the view property to the view in xib.

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Basically add a new ViewController from the object Library, set its custom class to your view controller's class (ThirdViewController), and finally drag a relation segue from your tab bar controller to this new view controller, which will embed it into the tab bar.

Comment: Yeah, I did that, but how do I get the .h and . m files to link it with that ThirdViewController?

Comment: As I mentioned, select the view controller in the storyboard, then open the utilities (RHS toolbar), select the third tab from left (identity inspector), and under custom class, set ThirdViewController. This will link it to your .h and .m